# POST to stripe API only works from the front end instead of lambda

Tags: api, lambda, request, stripe-payments

I want to post to the stripe API using the request library and my code is only successful when I post through the front end of my app (which I only did for testing purposes). Obviously I want to do this through lambda so I can use my stripe API key in the backend for security purposes. Here is my front end code:

```
await request({
                        url: 'https://api.stripe.com/v1/customers?email=' + currentSessionEmail + "&description=" + sessionUsername,
                        method: 'POST',
                        headers: {
                        'Authorization': 'Bearer my_key4534343432',
                          'Accept': 'application/json',
                          'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                          'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': "*",
                          "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": true
                        },
                        }, function (error, response, body) {
                        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                          console.log('BODY: ', body);
                          //var jsonResponse = JSON.parse(body); // turn response into JSON
        
                          // do stuff with the response and pass it to the callback...
                          //console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
        
                        }else{
                          alert(error);
                        }
                      });
```

My lambda function has the same code inside of it and it resolves with `200` but it does not execute the Stripe API properly otherwise I would see a customer created in my stripe dashboard which is not the case.

Comment: you should `console.log` your url and request as well. Maybe it's not the same.  In particular maybe your lambda is not seeing the same values of `url` and `body` as your main function is.  Also, don't put too much stock in the 200 status code.  It doesn't necessarily mean everything went well in Stripe.  Remember, they don't want to give too much information to hackers.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to make that POST request from the front end, as it requires your secret key.  You'll likely want to use https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node in your lambda function to make that happen server side.